# How to get specific json value - python

Tags: python, json, list, rest

I am migrating my code from java to python, but I am still having some difficulties understanding how to fetch a specific path in json using python.

This is my Java code, which returns a list of `accountsId`.

```
public static List < String > v02_JSON_counterparties(String date) {
    baseURI = "https://cdwp/cdw";
    String counterparties =
        given()
        .auth().basic(getJiraUser(), getJiraPass())
        .param("limit", "1000000")
        .param("count", "false")
        .when()
        .get("/counterparties/" + date).body().asString();

    List < String > accountId = extract_accountId(counterparties);
    return accountId;
}

public static List < String > extract_accountId(String res) {
    List < String > ids = JsonPath.read(res, "$..identifier[?(@.accountIdType == 'ACCOUNTID')].accountId");
    return ids;
}
```

And this is the json structure where I am getting the `accountID`.

```
{
            'organisationId': {
                '#value': 'MHI'
            },
            'accountName': 'LAZARD AM DEUT AC LF1632',
            'identifiers': {
                'accountId': 'LAZDLF1632',
                'customerId': 'LAZAMDEUSG',
                'blockAccountCode': 'LAZDEUBDBL',
                'bic': 'LAMDDEF1XXX',
                'identifier': [{
                    'accountId': 'MHI',
                    'accountIdType': 'REVNCNTR'
                }, {
                    'accountId': 'LAZDLF1632',
                    'accountIdType': 'ACCOUNTID'
                }, {
                    'accountId': 'LAZAMDEUSG',
                    'accountIdType': 'MHICUSTID'
                }, {
                    'accountId': 'LAZDEUBDBL',
                    'accountIdType': 'BLOCKACCOUNT'
                }, {
                    'accountId': 'LAMDDEF1XXX',
                    'accountIdType': 'ACCOUNTBIC'
                }, {
                    'accountId': 'LAZDLF1632',
                    'accountIdType': 'GLOBEOP'
                }]
            },
            'isBlocAccount': 'N',
            'accountStatus': 'COMPLETE',
            'products': {
                'productType': [{
                    'productLineName': 'CASH',
                    'productTypeId': 'PRODMHI1',
                    'productTypeName': 'Bond, Equity,Convertible Bond',
                    'cleared': 'N',
                    'bilateral': 'N',
                    'limitInstructions': {
                        'limitInstruction': [{
                            'limitAmount': '0',
                            'limitCurrency': 'GBP',
                            'limitType': 'PEAEXPLI',
                            'limitTypeName': 'Cash-Peak Exposure Limit'
                        }]
                    }
                }]
            },
            'etc': {
                'addressGeneral': 'LZFLUS33XXX',
                'addressAccount': 'LF1632',
                'tradingLevel': 'B'
            },
            'clientBroker': 'C',
            'costCentre': 'Credit Sales',
            'clientLevel': 'SUBAC',
            'accountCreationDate': '2016-10-19T00:00:00.000Z',
            'accountOpeningDate': '2016-10-19T00:00:00.000Z'
        }
```

This is my code in Python

```
import json, requests, urllib.parse, re
from pandas.io.parsers import read_csv
import pandas as pd
from termcolor import colored
import numpy as np
from glob import glob
import os

# Set Up
dateinplay = "2021-09-27"

#Get accountId
cdwCounterparties = (
    f"http://cdwu/cdw/counterparties/?limit=1000000?yyyy-mm-dd={dateinplay}"
)
r = json.loads(requests.get(cdwCounterparties).text)

account_ids = [i['accountId'] for i in data['identifiers']['identifier']if i['accountIdType']=="ACCOUNTID"]
```

I am getting this error when I try to fetch the accountId:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "h:\DESKTOP\test_check\checkCounterpartie.py", line 54, in <module>
    account_ids = [i['accountId'] for i in data['identifiers']['identifier']if i['accountIdType']=="ACCOUNTID"]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: Show us what you have attempted in Python first and see if you come into a problem

Comment: The same way that you would get the value out of the data structure if it *didn't* come from JSON. If you don't understand how to manipulate lists and dictionaries in Python, you need to follow a general tutorial. Python's built-in JSON library doesn't have a "path" idiom; it just creates a data structure representing the whole thing, and then you work with that data structure normally.

Comment: Anyway, "please help me convert code from one language to another" is not an actionable Stack Overflow question. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users. You are expected to make an attempt to solve the problem yourself - in the language you are asking about - first.

Comment: sorry guys for the type of question, I should have added what I already had in python. 
I edited the post ad what I have so far, but it is giving me error to interact with the list of the json response.
I edited and added the code that I have so far in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm inerpeting your question correctly you want all ids where accountistype is "ACCOUNTID".

this give you that:

```py
 account_ids = [i['accountId'] for i in data['identifiers']['identifier']if i['accountIdType']=="ACCOUNTID"]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it's returning this error. TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str.

Comment: cdwCounterparties = (
    f"http://cdwu/cdw/counterparties/?limit=1000000?yyyy-mm-dd={dateinplay}"
)
data = json.loads(requests.get(cdwCounterparties).text)

account_ids = [i['accountId'] for i in data['identifiers']['identifier']if i['accountIdType']=="ACCOUNTID"]

print(account_ids)

Comment: oh. then your json is probably nested or formatted differently than what you posted.  I can help you on chat if you post the actual data you are getting in return from the response

Comment: I have updated the json response in the post.

Comment: This is strange. When i paste your json my code works. Are you shure you are getting The data as a dict? Try chacking The type of data `>>> type(data)
<class 'dict'>` it should return this. If your data object is not a dict you can try using the .json property instead of the .text on your request

Comment: Never mind it I see you are using json.loads. So it should be a dict.

Comment: The error message is telling me that you have a list somewhere we think there is a dict. Is your json actually larger and what you posted is just one of the elements in a list of dicts?

Answer (score 0):

```
accs = {
  "identifiers": {
...
account_id_list = []
for acc in accs.get("identifiers", {}).get("identifier", []):
    account_id_list.append(acc.get("accountId", ""))
```

creates a list called account_id_list which is

```
['MHI',  'DKEPBNPGIV',  'DKEPLLP SG',  'DAVKEMEQBL',  '401821',  'DKEPGB21XXX',  'DKEPBNPGIV',  'DKPARTNR']
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you store the dictionary (json structure) in variable `x`, getting all `accountIDs` is something like:

```
account_ids = [i['accountId'] for i in x['identifiers']['identifier']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to thank you all for your answers. It helped me a lot to find a resolution to my problem.
Below is how I solved it.

```
listAccountId = []
cdwCounterparties = (
f"http://cdwu/cdw/counterparties/?limit=100000?yyyy-mm-dd={dateinplay}"
)

r = requests.get(cdwCounterparties).json()

jsonpath_expression = parse("$..accounts.account[*].identifiers.identifier[*]")

for match in jsonpath_expression.find(r):
    # print(f'match id: {match.value}')
    thisdict = match.value
    if thisdict["accountIdType"] == "ACCOUNTID":
        #   print(thisdict["accountId"])
        listAccountId.append(thisdict["accountId"])
```